# Coldfusion - Using CFIF with JSON Data

Tags: json, coldfusion

I'm working with a web API, which is returning the following data (this is a cfdump of the cfhttp.filecontent);

```
{"id":"xxx","service1":["xxx"],"service2":["xxx"]}
```

I need to be able to read this and determine if a service is on the list.  For example,

```
<cfscript>
pdata = deserializeJSON(cfhttp.FileContent);
</cfscript>

<cfif IsDefined(pdata.service1)>Do something</cfif>
```

However, I'm receiving an error with the above code.  I've only recently started working with JSON, and so far I've had reasonable success - but I'm stuck with this!

Any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: Fortunately this problem was easier to spot than others. But in future, *always* post the error message. It will take far less time to get an answer when people do not have to "guess" what the problem is..

Comment: It's recommended practice to use StructKeyExists instead of IsDefined.  `<cfif StructKeyExists(pdata, "service1")>...</cfif>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `IsDefined("pdata.service1")`

> With isDefined() CF needs to know the name of the variable you are asking about. A name is a string, so you pass in a string.

I found it to be a little counter-intuitive at first, but JasonDean put it into perspective in the comments.

Comment: Thanks! That's a sure sign I've been looking at this too long, you are indeed correct - I was missing the quotations.

Comment: No worries, don't forget to accept. :) It happens to me alot, CF error handling is pretty descriptive most of the time and can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I don't think it is counter-intuitive at all. With isDefined() CF needs to know the name of the variable you are asking about. A name is a string, so you pass in a string. How could it expect a variable to be passed in? If the variable doesn't exist, how can it be passed in? It's all in how you think about it.

Comment: @JasonDean Thanks, I never thought of it that way but it makes sense. I wasn't formally trained in CF, just thrown into the deep end. I added that information to the answer.